# Python Pytest: show full variables values on error (no minimization)

Tags: python, pytest

I am using pytest 3.9 on Python 3.6 and did not find the answer to this question in pytest docs.

I have some test cases which involves checking if a given key is in a dictionary. When that key is not there, pytest shows the failure, but it somehow "reduces" the dictionary value, showing only some of its values.
Same thing happens when outputting local variables values (dicts and lists are reduced so that only some values are shown).

Is there any way to disable that "value minimization" and show the full variable value instead ?

Example test case that shows this behavior:

```
def test_in():
    d = {key: key for key in range(500)} # makes d sufficiently big to trigger minimization of output
    assert 1000 in d # this will fail
```

shows:

```
================ FAILURES ===========
________________ test_in ___________

def test_in():
        d = {key: key for key in range(500)}
>       assert 1000 in d 
E       assert 1000 in {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, ...}
```

I would like to have the full value of `d` instead of that abbreviated value. This would help me analyze some of the failure cases.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

#### Using `--showlocals`

If you just need the full variables printing, you can use the `--showlocals` option, combined with the verbose output. Example:

```
$ pytest -vvl
==================================== test session starts ====================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.6, pytest-3.9.1, py-1.5.4, pluggy-0.7.1
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /Users/hoefling/projects/private/stackoverflow, inifile:
collected 1 item

test_spam.py::test_in FAILED                                                          [100%]

========================================= FAILURES ==========================================
__________________________________________ test_in __________________________________________

    def test_in():
        d = {key: key for key in range(500)} # makes d sufficiently big to trigger minimization of output
>       assert 1000 in d # this will fail
E       assert 1000 in {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, ...}

d          = {0: 0,
 1: 1,
 2: 2,
 3: 3,
 4: 4,
 5: 5,
 6: 6,
 7: 7,
 8: 8,
 9: 9,
 10: 10,
```

etc.

#### Custom `pytest_assertrepr_compare` hook

Another option is to redefine the specific assertion messages via [`pytest_assertrepr_compare`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_assertrepr_compare) hook. In the example below, I redefine assertion for `el in dict` checks. This will be automatically applied to all matching assertions in all tests:

```
# conftest.py

def pytest_assertrepr_compare(op, left, right):
    if op == 'in' and isinstance(right, dict):
        return [f'{left} in {right}']
```

Running `pytest -vv` will now yield the full dict as no no truncating is done in custom hook:

```
$ pytest -vv
================================== test session starts ===================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.6, pytest-3.9.1, py-1.5.4, pluggy-0.7.1
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /Users/hoefling/projects/private/stackoverflow, inifile:
collected 1 item

test_spam.py::test_in FAILED                                                       [100%]

======================================== FAILURES ========================================
________________________________________ test_in _________________________________________

    def test_in():
        d = {key: key for key in range(500)} # makes d sufficiently big to trigger minimization of output
>       assert 1000 in d # this will fail
E       assert 1000 in {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9, 10: 10, 11: 11, 12: 12, 13: 13, 14: 14, 15: 15, 16: 16, 17: 17, 18: 18, 19: 19, 20: 20, 21: 21, 22: 22, 23: 23, 24: 24, 25: 25, 26: 26, 27: 27, 28: 28, 29: 29, 30: 30, 31: 31, 32: 32, 33: 33, 34: 34, 35: 35, 36: 36, 37: 37, 38: 38, 39: 39, 40: 40, 41: 41, 42: 42, 43: 43, 44: 44, 45: 45, 46: 46, 47: 47, 48: 48, 49: 49, 50: 50, 51: 51, 52: 52, 53: 53, 54: 54, 55: 55, 56: 56, 57: 57, 58: 58, 59: 59, 60: 60, 61: 61, 62: 62, 63: 63, 64: 64, 65: 65, 66: 66, 67: 67, 68: 68, 69: 69, 70: 70, 71: 71, 72: 72, 73: 73, 74: 74, 75: 75, 76: 76, 77: 77, 78: 78, 79: 79, 80: 80, 81: 81, 82: 82, 83: 83, 84: 84, 85: 85, 86: 86, 87: 87, 88: 88, 89: 89, 90: 90, 91: 91, 92: 92, 93: 93, 94: 94, 95: 95, 96: 96, 97: 97, 98: 98, 99: 99, 100: 100, 101: 101, 102: 102, 103: 103, 104: 104, 105: 105, 106: 106, 107: 107, 108: 108, 109: 109, 110: 110, 111: 111, 112: 112, 113: 113, 114: 114, 115: 115, 116: 116, 117: 117, 118: 118, 119: 119, 120: 120, 121: 121, 122: 122, 123: 123, 124: 124, 125: 125, 126: 126, 127: 127, 128: 128, 129: 129, 130: 130, 131: 131, 132: 132, 133: 133, 134: 134, 135: 135, 136: 136, 137: 137, 138: 138, 139: 139, 140: 140, 141: 141, 142: 142, 143: 143, 144: 144, 145: 145, 146: 146, 147: 147, 148: 148, 149: 149, 150: 150, 151: 151, 152: 152, 153: 153, 154: 154, 155: 155, 156: 156, 157: 157, 158: 158, 159: 159, 160: 160, 161: 161, 162: 162, 163: 163, 164: 164, 165: 165, 166: 166, 167: 167, 168: 168, 169: 169, 170: 170, 171: 171, 172: 172, 173: 173, 174: 174, 175: 175, 176: 176, 177: 177, 178: 178, 179: 179, 180: 180, 181: 181, 182: 182, 183: 183, 184: 184, 185: 185, 186: 186, 187: 187, 188: 188, 189: 189, 190: 190, 191: 191, 192: 192, 193: 193, 194: 194, 195: 195, 196: 196, 197: 197, 198: 198, 199: 199, 200: 200, 201: 201, 202: 202, 203: 203, 204: 204, 205: 205, 206: 206, 207: 207, 208: 208, 209: 209, 210: 210, 211: 211, 212: 212, 213: 213, 214: 214, 215: 215, 216: 216, 217: 217, 218: 218, 219: 219, 220: 220, 221: 221, 222: 222, 223: 223, 224: 224, 225: 225, 226: 226, 227: 227, 228: 228, 229: 229, 230: 230, 231: 231, 232: 232, 233: 233, 234: 234, 235: 235, 236: 236, 237: 237, 238: 238, 239: 239, 240: 240, 241: 241, 242: 242, 243: 243, 244: 244, 245: 245, 246: 246, 247: 247, 248: 248, 249: 249, 250: 250, 251: 251, 252: 252, 253: 253, 254: 254, 255: 255, 256: 256, 257: 257, 258: 258, 259: 259, 260: 260, 261: 261, 262: 262, 263: 263, 264: 264, 265: 265, 266: 266, 267: 267, 268: 268, 269: 269, 270: 270, 271: 271, 272: 272, 273: 273, 274: 274, 275: 275, 276: 276, 277: 277, 278: 278, 279: 279, 280: 280, 281: 281, 282: 282, 283: 283, 284: 284, 285: 285, 286: 286, 287: 287, 288: 288, 289: 289, 290: 290, 291: 291, 292: 292, 293: 293, 294: 294, 295: 295, 296: 296, 297: 297, 298: 298, 299: 299, 300: 300, 301: 301, 302: 302, 303: 303, 304: 304, 305: 305, 306: 306, 307: 307, 308: 308, 309: 309, 310: 310, 311: 311, 312: 312, 313: 313, 314: 314, 315: 315, 316: 316, 317: 317, 318: 318, 319: 319, 320: 320, 321: 321, 322: 322, 323: 323, 324: 324, 325: 325, 326: 326, 327: 327, 328: 328, 329: 329, 330: 330, 331: 331, 332: 332, 333: 333, 334: 334, 335: 335, 336: 336, 337: 337, 338: 338, 339: 339, 340: 340, 341: 341, 342: 342, 343: 343, 344: 344, 345: 345, 346: 346, 347: 347, 348: 348, 349: 349, 350: 350, 351: 351, 352: 352, 353: 353, 354: 354, 355: 355, 356: 356, 357: 357, 358: 358, 359: 359, 360: 360, 361: 361, 362: 362, 363: 363, 364: 364, 365: 365, 366: 366, 367: 367, 368: 368, 369: 369, 370: 370, 371: 371, 372: 372, 373: 373, 374: 374, 375: 375, 376: 376, 377: 377, 378: 378, 379: 379, 380: 380, 381: 381, 382: 382, 383: 383, 384: 384, 385: 385, 386: 386, 387: 387, 388: 388, 389: 389, 390: 390, 391: 391, 392: 392, 393: 393, 394: 394, 395: 395, 396: 396, 397: 397, 398: 398, 399: 399, 400: 400, 401: 401, 402: 402, 403: 403, 404: 404, 405: 405, 406: 406, 407: 407, 408: 408, 409: 409, 410: 410, 411: 411, 412: 412, 413: 413, 414: 414, 415: 415, 416: 416, 417: 417, 418: 418, 419: 419, 420: 420, 421: 421, 422: 422, 423: 423, 424: 424, 425: 425, 426: 426, 427: 427, 428: 428, 429: 429, 430: 430, 431: 431, 432: 432, 433: 433, 434: 434, 435: 435, 436: 436, 437: 437, 438: 438, 439: 439, 440: 440, 441: 441, 442: 442, 443: 443, 444: 444, 445: 445, 446: 446, 447: 447, 448: 448, 449: 449, 450: 450, 451: 451, 452: 452, 453: 453, 454: 454, 455: 455, 456: 456, 457: 457, 458: 458, 459: 459, 460: 460, 461: 461, 462: 462, 463: 463, 464: 464, 465: 465, 466: 466, 467: 467, 468: 468, 469: 469, 470: 470, 471: 471, 472: 472, 473: 473, 474: 474, 475: 475, 476: 476, 477: 477, 478: 478, 479: 479, 480: 480, 481: 481, 482: 482, 483: 483, 484: 484, 485: 485, 486: 486, 487: 487, 488: 488, 489: 489, 490: 490, 491: 491, 492: 492, 493: 493, 494: 494, 495: 495, 496: 496, 497: 497, 498: 498, 499: 499}

test_spam.py:3: AssertionError
================================ 1 failed in 0.08 seconds ================================
```

Comment: I tried `-v` but not `-vv`. I confirm that using extra-verbose output with `-vv` does what I want, both for variables output by `--show-locales` and for assertion failures. Thanks for the detailed answer!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 8):

You can explicitly specify a failure message in the `assert` statement:

```
def test_int():
    d = {key: key for key in range(500)}
    assert 1000 in d, f"1000 is not in {d}"
```

Unfortunately, this has to be done for every `assert` statement where you want to print the whole dictionary. The advantage however is that you can customize the output to match your needs.

Also note, that you must convert the dictionary into a string, otherwise pytest is smart enough to simplify it.

```
assert 1000 in d, d
```

This will print

```
E    AssertionError: {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, ...}
E    assert 1000 in {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, ...}
```

While

```
assert 1000 in d, str(d)
```

will display the whole dictionary again.

Comment: This solution is also independent of verbosity level of the pytest log.

Comment: Note, that you must really turn the variable into a Python str(). Even a bytes() object will not work and will be truncated instead. So I added `, myvar.decode("utf8")` behind my assert statements.

Answer (score 1):

Run with the `-l` flag, it will show the local variables.
eg `pytest -l`